# Disable back button text

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller

I want to disable the back button text in Xamarin iOS, 
along with the button itself. I already disabled the back button itself but the text is left.

[image]

Does anyone know of any way to disabling the text as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this in two ways:

```
NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, false);
```

or

```
NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = null;
```

If you use the second solution, then you would have to recreate the button if you ever want to make it visible again.

Comment: Hey - thanks so much for the response. Like I stated in my question I know how to hide the back Button. But I dont know how to hide the Back Button text. This line here NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, false); works to hide the button but not the text to the right of it, as you can see in my image I provided.

Answer (score 1):

With Navigation Page:-

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, ""); //Empty string as title
```

or hide the Back button with:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

Comment: Im using Xamarin IOS native and i dont think NavigationPage is supported, NavigationItem..SetHasBackButton(this, false); works to hide the button but not the text.

Comment: Check it please [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/)